# IronPDF: CS0618: Class 'IronPdf.HtmlHeaderFooter' is obsolete: 'Please use the newer API class IronPdf.HtmlHeaderFooter'

Tags: ironpdf

Since the latest version (2022.4.0.5575) I get an obsolete warning on the `HtmlHeaderFooter` class in IronPdf:

CS0618: Class 'IronPdf.HtmlHeaderFooter' is obsolete: 'Please use the newer API class IronPdf.HtmlHeaderFooter'

```cs
using IronPdf;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class IronPdfHelper
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            var x = new HtmlHeaderFooter(); // CS0618 warning here
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, I am using the correct class. There is no other HtmlHeaderFooter class. Does this mean that the obsolete message is wrong (a bug)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug - a false deprecated message in IronPdf 2022.4.5575

It has been resolved in the newest release [IronPdf 2022.5.5596](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPdf/), released 2022-05-02